# Benchmarking with Bonnie++

Tags: benchmarking, io

I need some help in interpreting this Bonnie++ results. These are the results from two VMs with Ubuntu 14.04 with identical hardware resources. One is running apache web server, other is running MySQL.

This is the results from one test on each machine using this command.

```
sudo bonnie++ -d / -n 5 -m dats28-web-2 -s 1024 -r 200 -u root > bout1.dat
```

Here are the results. Why are *Latency Seq Read* and *Latency Rewrite* so much higher on the webserver? All other test results are nearly equal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't actually have the answer to your question (I came here hoping for an answer) but I did find a similar question with an answer.

https://serverfault.com/questions/221976/hd-latency-measurement-using-bonnie-on-different-machines-with-different-ram-s